# How can I combine the filter and countifs functions in excel/sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, filter, countif

In a separate sheet called "Sales Tracker Integration" I'm looking to filter out duplicates in column C ($C2:$C), and the count the number of rows that contain "text string A" or "text string B"

=COUNTIFS(UNIQUE('Sales Tracker Integration'!$C$2:$C),"<>"&"",FILTER('Sales Tracker Integration'!$A:$S, 'Sales Tracker Integration'!$I:$I<>"No Action Taken", 'Sales Tracker Integration'!$I:$I<>""))

Can't get the formula to work, so I just did a manual workaround - copied the data and deleted the repeat rows and did it that way, but if I can get this filter correct, my dashboard would be real time :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect only the number? You can try with COUNTUNIQUEIFS:

```
    =COUNTUNIQUEIFS(Sales Tracker Integration'!$C$2:$C,
'Sales Tracker Integration'!$C$2:$C,"<>"&"",
'Sales Tracker Integration'!$I$2:$I,"<>"&"No Action Taken", 
'Sales Tracker Integration'!$I$2:$I,"<>"&"")
```

Comment: OOO i think this could work! Thanks Martin. Question what's the "&" for after <>

Comment: I actually followed your lead from your formula, you possibly don't need it when you actually have a string after it